# How to fix 'No table found' error using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to extract data from a table on a webpage into a pandas dataframe.
The website is **https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/passing/2019/1** . I'm using selenium and the chrome webdriver. I believe my issue is that I cannot identify the table's element id. I have no experience with html so am having a tough time troubleshooting.

I've tried using pandas' built-in read_html() function but was met with a 'No Tables Found' error. I switched over to selenium and am using a chrome webdriver, but still have the same error. I've also tried adding a delay to let the page load, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
# scrape webpage
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/passing/2019/1')

html = driver.page_source
tables = pd.read_html(html)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-e2e5cae6f0b5> in <module>
      1 url = f'https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/passing/2019/1'
----> 2 tats_list = pd.read_html(url)

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only)
   1103         na_values=na_values,
   1104         keep_default_na=keep_default_na,
-> 1105         displayed_only=displayed_only,
   1106     )

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    910             break
    911     else:
--> 912         raise_with_traceback(retained)
    913 
    914     ret = []

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
     45     if traceback == Ellipsis:
     46         _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
---> 47     raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
     48 
     49 

ValueError: No tables found
```

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
# scrape webpage
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

html = driver.page_source
# find table by using suspected table id
tables = driver.find_element_by_id("gs-data-table")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-5596e919e5ff> in <module>
      5 html = driver.page_source
      6 
----> 7 tables = driver.find_element_by_id("gs-data-table")

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_id(self, id_)
    358             element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
    359         """
--> 360         return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
    361 
    362     def find_elements_by_id(self, id_):

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="gs-data-table"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
```

I expected the output to be a dataframe of the table located on the webpage but cannot get around this error. Any help in alternative methods, or help identifying the tables element id would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/passing/2019/1")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
table_id=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-table__body-wrapper']//tbody");

rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") # get all of the rows in the table
for row in rows:
    # Get the columns (all the column 2)
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1] #note: index start from 0, 1 is col 2
    print col.text #prints text from the element
```